# Which programmer/connector can I use for a 6 pin header on mechanical keyboard design?

Tags: pcb-design, keyboard

Forgive me, I am not an engineer but I wanted to figure out which connector I should use to program my custom mechanical keyboard design. The PCB has an Atmega32u4 controller which is connected to a 6 pin header.

I am adding more detail to my question because other members requested it so they understand my question better. I used to make custom keyboards using QMK plus Adafruit feather boards and it was easy to program them because I can just plug in a usb cable and get started.

Now, I am trying to learn how I can program a controller like the Atmega32u4 directly on the PCB. My friend helped me design the PCB and but I didn't get a chance to ask him everything about the design. I did some research and found that the 6-pin header on the PCB board is how I can program the controller. I can easily solder the header but I don't know what to do after that. I assume there is some sort of connector or cable I should be using. Thanks in advance! 
[image]

Comment: This depends on the programmer that you are using, this is either a male or female standard 6 pin header. What programmer are you using?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Jonathan :-) It's a bit difficult to interpret your question. Can you edit your question and add a lot of detail, explaining the background of what you're doing and why. The better your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: Thank you! I have added a bit more detail. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the programmed MCU is an AVR, you buy an AVR programmer that connects to the programmed board via the connector in your question, and to your PC via USB.

The programming pinheader you seem to have has all its 6 pins in a single row. Standard AVR programming cables I have used have had 2x3 pin connectors, and 2x5 pin connectors, so you might want to build your own cable between your device and whatever AVR programming device you buy.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand what I am dealing with now. 

Answer (score 0):

A 0.100" square post header is probably the most cheapest and most common. You can get much fancier connectors that also have 6-pins though.